# How can I using Javascript Swap Out A h2 URL Destination with Limited Access to HTML?

Tags: java, javascript, url, swap

I don't have access to my HTML code but I have access to Javascript in the footer of my document. With that being said I would like to switch out the URL "/vistor_signup" with a new URL of my choosing. Lets say "http://www.example.com/account_signup"

And I would also like to do the same for "/user_signup", lets say swap to "http://www.example.com/master_signup"

I have to use JavaScript to do so and I don't have any understanding of JS.

How do I make this work with JS code?

#### My code

```
<div class="grid_12">
<div id="login">
<div class="panel" id="login-form">
<div id="login-promo">
<div class="clear"></div>

<h2><a href="/vistor_signup">Visitor Sign-Up</a> ></h2>

<h2><a href="/user_signup">User Sign-Up</a> ></h2>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To what do you have access? If you can't edit the HTML, you can't inject JS. Do you have access to the file system or .htaccess?

Comment: I have full access to edit/add, Javascript in the footer and full access to my CSS page. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this:

```
var anchors = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var anc = anchors[i];
  if (anc.getAttribute("href") == "/visitor_signup") { 
    anc.setAttribute("href", "http://www.example.com/account_signup");
  } 
}
```

**WARNING**: due to the way browser render HTML (parsing the page, semi-sequentially fetching referenced resources, evaluating javascript along the way), it might happen that someone sees the html before your script gets executed, and even clicks the '/visitor_signup' link.

Comment: How do I switch "/vistor_signup" to this link "hxxp://www.mysite.com/account_signup"?

Comment: `for each (... in ...)`  Don't use such non-standard things for iterating over an array. It's intended for objects only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

Comment: Just replace "/account_signup" of milan's answer with "hxxp://www.mysite.com/account_signup"

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't edit the HTML and the `<h2>`s aren't differentiated, using jQuery might be easier than using plain JS in order to reach the elements.

This jQuery could be:

```
$('#login-promo h2:first a').attr("href", "/account_signup").parent().next().find('a').attr("href", "/master_signup");
```

Here we are selecting the first `<h2> <a>` and changing its href. Then we go back tho the `<a>`s parent, find the next `<h2> <a>`and change its href too.

You can check an example in [this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8VVGS/1/)

Comment: Then you could accept this answer as well as the answers to your other questions that helped you :P

Answer (score 0):

Under your limitations, esp.

- No access to code
- No id tag on elements

your best bet is to

- use document.body.GetElementsByTagName() to find all  tags
- on those check the href property
- change it accordingly

EDIT: This is exactly what @milan's answer does, so please disregard this one